# Red border surrounding cell overlaps row header when scrolling

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I’m having a problem while using the DataGrid object with row headers.
Each row of the table contains an object that implements the iDataErrorInfo interface and when a cell has an error and a horizontal scroll happens, the red border of the cell overlaps the row header.

How can I solve the problem and avoid the overlapping?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  RowHeaderWidth="200" 
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                  HeadersVisibility="All">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                    Width="700" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=LastName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                    Width="700" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="FullName" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=FullName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                    Width="700" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```